# Suddenly, any time I run NPM i *Package Name* nothing is installed, but I get no errors and it says it installed

Tags: npm-install

I've never had this problem until now, but no matter what I try to install in my project it looks fine in the terminal and says everything was installed with no errors, but nothing shows up in the package.json file.

The only new thing I've done is I recently started trying to learn NextJS and i needed to update to a newer version of node, so I'm not sure if that's suddenly why this is happening now, but even in my regular JS projects not using Next I'm running into this problem.

I have no idea how to fix this issue...

This is my package.json file after doing npm init -y and it's the same after doing npm i express:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio-v2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I've updated my VS Code, updated node and npm to the latest versions, so i now have node v21.6.2 and npm v 10.2.4 and that didn't help solve my problem. So if someone recommends using different versions please let me know.

I've tried creating new projects and just doing an npm init -y then tried installing express and still nothing gets installed.
I've tried clearing the cache, but I'm scared to try a lot of the other things I've read since I'm not exactly clear on what they are doing and I'm scared of making the problem worse.

Comment: Are you sure you're running this in the right directory? Can you try it with `--save` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried doing this in the root and my client directory, but neither works. I just tried it with --save and still nothing.